# What does brush.event do when animating brush events?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, d3.js, meteor

#### The Question:

While checking out the [Brush Snapping](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6232537) feature posted on bl.ocks.org, I became confounded by this block of code:

```
var gBrush = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(brush)
        .call(brush.event);
```

To be clear, I understand what `.call(brush.event)` does, but I don't understand why it is *in this particular block of code*.  I.e., I see that this same call is made in the "brushended" event handler, but why do the transitions in the 'brushend' event depend on the call copied above?

---

#### Prior Research:

I checked out the [API docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#brush_on), which said the following, but I must admit I don't really understand this explanation.

> If selection is a transition, registers the appropriate tweens so that the brush dispatches events over the course of the transition

I need some help parsing out the nitty gritty mechanics on that call to `brush.event`?

---

#### (Reason I Want to Know):

I want to implement this feature into a Meteor.js application.  I turns out, if I comment out this one line, the slider snaps into place, but the animation is lost.  If I leave the line in though, the brush selection never shows up at all.  I'm asking about the mechanics of this animation in order to figure out how to make it work in my meteor project

**Update:** It turns out the [package named "d3" on atmosphere is deprecated](https://github.com/sergeyt/meteor-d3/issues/3#event-230586722).  If I use the package named d3.js:d3, everything works cherry.

---

#### Full Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.axis text {
  font: 11px sans-serif;
}

.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid-background {
  fill: #ddd;
}

.grid line,
.grid path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid .minor.tick line {
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #000;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 200, right: 40, bottom: 200, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(2013, 7, 1), new Date(2013, 7, 15) - 1])
    .range([0, width]);

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x)
    .extent([new Date(2013, 7, 2), new Date(2013, 7, 3)])
    .on("brushend", brushended);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "grid-background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(d3.time.hours, 12)
        .tickSize(-height)
        .tickFormat(""))
  .selectAll(".tick")
    .classed("minor", function(d) { return d.getHours(); });

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(d3.time.days)
      .tickPadding(0))
  .selectAll("text")
    .attr("x", 6)
    .style("text-anchor", null);

var gBrush = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.event);

gBrush.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("height", height);

function brushended() {
  if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return; // only transition after input
  var extent0 = brush.extent(),
      extent1 = extent0.map(d3.time.day.round);

  // if empty when rounded, use floor & ceil instead
  if (extent1[0] >= extent1[1]) {
    extent1[0] = d3.time.day.floor(extent0[0]);
    extent1[1] = d3.time.day.ceil(extent0[1]);
  }

  d3.select(this).transition()
      .call(brush.extent(extent1))
      .call(brush.event);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in the API docs just before the bit you've quoted:

> This can be useful in triggering listeners after setting the brush extent programatically.

In this particular example, calling `brush.event` is necessary because the extent is set programmatically (this is how the snapping is implemented). If it wasn't called, the shown brush extent wouldn't correspond to what's set for the scales, as the extent would be adjusted in the brush hander function and never updated.

However, in the *particular* bit of code you've posted, you don't actually need to call `brush.event` -- it's only necessary inside the brush handler function (see [example with that first call removed](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/9e1e0604ea9a19e8b901)).

Now, on to the transition. First, let's see what happens when we remove it -- see [example here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/5dd84ba8320f5d838912). The brush now snaps instead of gradually moving into place. Otherwise there's no difference.

The part of the documentation that you've quoted basically says that everything that needs to be taken care of in order to make the transition work is done. Technically, the transition lets all the appropriate listeners know that it's moving the brush so that linked displays would be updated (think for example a chart as in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367)).

As far as your application is concerned, it sounds as if something else was interfering with the brush, i.e. (re)setting the state after the transition has started.

Update: The events dispatched during the transition don't actually trigger your handler because you're returning if this is the case in the first line of `brushend` event handler. What you're doing when calling `brush.event` is installing handler functions, not handling individual events -- *all* the events dispatched afterwards will be handled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Still don't really get why the  necessary to animate the brush.event is necessary though.  First of all, we've already got on in the "brushened" callback.  Second of all, why does this call to event persist to affect the animation at all once it's been called the first time?

Comment: I realize my question wasn't totally clear.  I just edited it above.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you mean, but I've updated the answer with some more explanations. Let me know if there's anything that's unclear.

Comment: shouldn't this block of code in the brush event handle the whole transition: d3.select(this).transition()
      .call(brush.extent(extent1))
      .call(brush.event);

Comment: It does. This is what gradually moves the brush to the closest day.

Comment: I don't totally get it, but I'll give you the answer flag, because I appreciate your help.

Comment: Well if you explain what's unclear further maybe I'll get it and give you the answer you're looking for :)